# Remove Woocommerce standard wrapper <div class="woocommerce columns-''>

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I use custom theme with woocommerce. My main page displays products by categories and they are wrapped in the standard woocommerce block  `<div class="woocommerce columns-4">`. I need to remove it. In woocommerce folder i found just a single reference about this block in woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php

```
return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
```

I tried to change it to `return '';`,  but still have the same wrapper.

 
Is there any option to remove this block?

Function with `<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>'` is below.

```
public static function product_categories( $atts ) { public static function product_categories( $atts ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    if ( isset( $atts['number'] ) ) {
        $atts['limit'] = $atts['number'];
    }

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit'      => '-1',
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'columns'    => '4',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'parent'     => '',
        'ids'        => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_categories' );

    $ids        = array_filter( array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['ids'] ) ) );
    $hide_empty = ( true === $atts['hide_empty'] || 'true' === $atts['hide_empty'] || 1 === $atts['hide_empty'] || '1' === $atts['hide_empty'] ) ? 1 : 0;

    // Get terms and workaround WP bug with parents/pad counts.
    $args = array(
        'orderby'    => $atts['orderby'],
        'order'      => $atts['order'],
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
        'include'    => $ids,
        'pad_counts' => true,
        'child_of'   => $atts['parent'],
    );

    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

    if ( '' !== $atts['parent'] ) {
        $product_categories = wp_list_filter( $product_categories, array(
            'parent' => $atts['parent'],
        ) );
    }

    if ( $hide_empty ) {
        foreach ( $product_categories as $key => $category ) {
            if ( 0 === $category->count ) {
                unset( $product_categories[ $key ] );
            }
        }
    }

    $atts['limit'] = '-1' === $atts['limit'] ? null : intval( $atts['limit'] );
    if ( $atts['limit'] ) {
        $product_categories = array_slice( $product_categories, 0, $atts['limit'] );
    }

    $columns = absint( $atts['columns'] );
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

    ob_start();

    if ( $product_categories ) {
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();

        foreach ( $product_categories as $category ) {
            wc_get_template( 'content-product_cat.php', array(
                'category' => $category,
            ) );
        }

        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    }

    woocommerce_reset_loop();

    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Obvious question... did you save the changes? Your page may also be cached in your browser, try reloading it with SHIFt + F5 and see if that reflects the changes.

Comment: Yes, I've saved it and cleared cache but this block is still there.

Comment: What if you change it to something strange- just to make sure that is the actual place the code is coming from. Which you kind of already have. So does this <div...> appear anywhere else?

Comment: Nothing was changed even when I deleted whole function mentioned above. I searched this <div...> in Sublime and It's the only place where this <div...> was. So I can't understand if it isn't actual place the code is coming from what is.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure this will help but its worth a shot... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675604/where-can-i-add-another-class-for-woocommerce-wrapper

Comment: @ShakhA. I assume you want to change the number of columns in the product grid?

Comment: @AwaisUmar I need to remove this <div> because it blocks flexbox from another custom <div> . If there is no option to remove it i'll try to edit it with css, but it's not the best solution =\

Comment: @ShakhA. I've checked the related function of the WC. It would be possible to remove the $column class from it. Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

if you removed woocommerce from the class many of your site's woocommerce functionality may crash.
its not recommended if you want to add custom-class just use jquery.addclass

```
$('#yourid').addClass('class-to-be-added');
$('#yourid').removeClass('class-to-be-removed');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following jQuery code:

```
<script>
   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
      var proUL = jQuery( ".products" );
      if ( proUL.parent().is( "div" ) ) {
         jQuery( ".products" ).unwrap();
      }
   });
</script>
```