# how to remove woocommerce container div '<div class="woocommerce">'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom theme for woocommerce an copied `templates` folder to my theme root`woocommerce`. now I figured that all pages in woocommerce has a div container with class `woocommerce`. I want to change the class of it or remove that from my theme. I searched in my theme files `<div class="woocommerce">` and I found nothing. ! 
is there any way to change or delete that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't change or delete, which could break everything, read more here - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12191.

Comment: so what can i do for (wrap it into another div) ?

Comment: May I know the reason for removing this DIV?

Comment: i use bootstrap4 in my project and i want to use its grid for `my-account` page. also in some other page i have some changes.

Comment: Copy your theme's 'page.php' as 'woocommerce.php' in your theme root and replace `the_content()` with `woocommerce_content()`. Don't forget to remove the loop. Feel free to wrap any additional DIVs. Read more here - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/#section-2.

Comment: Not completely true, it is possible to change its output. Indeed, the WooCommerce plugin has not a filter function for that, but there's a method that allows you to change its html markup as also add additional css classes to it by directly "tapping" on the function which builds it. Here's a workaround for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56664962/1152876

Comment: Yes, you can add new class - but you should not delete or rename `woocommerce` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find because the word `<div class="woocommerce">` may be a parameter of a rendering function (example: `<div class="<?php echo $param">`) and you must find where php code is placed instead. When you get where it is placed, just add your class after parameter (example: `class="<?php echo $param?> your-class"`) to access this element