# Does it possible to remove or replace woocommerce class on checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom theme and I have moved woocommerce folder to my current custom theme but once i came to checkout page there is a div name `woocommerce` is still showing as main div. I want to hide or rename this div but I don't have any idea what `action` or `filter` hooks will be use for that.

I have also attached a image that showing woocommerce class name on check out page.
[image]

ALso I have used below hook for change main `woocommerce` class before checkout form but that will not remove or replace that `woocommerce` class.

```
function action_woocommerce_before_checkout_form( $checkout ) { 
    echo '<div class="checkout_section">';
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 10, 1 ); 



function action_woocommerce_after_checkout_form( $checkout ) {     
    echo '</div>';
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'action_woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 10, 1 );
```

Can anyone tell me which hook should i use for remove or replace that div?

Comment: You could find your answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675604/where-can-i-add-another-class-for-woocommerce-wrapper/) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569322/how-to-remove-woocommerce-container-div-div-class-woocommerce)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove woocommerce container div '<div class="woocommerce">'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569322/how-to-remove-woocommerce-container-div-div-class-woocommerce)