# Change Woocommerce wrapper 'div class=woocommerce' for "main class=woocommerce' html5 semantics

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to develop my store / site using new html5 semantics, so I have things like...

```
header
 - nav
main
 - section
 - article
footer
```

The issue is that when using woocommerce I now have

```
header
 - nav
div
 - section
 - article
footer
```

I see the code on woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php So I need your help to create a function to change and call this code on functions.php instead of changing woocommerce core files.

Below code is using main as I want, issue then is on core files so any update will override the change from main again to div.

```
/**
 * Shortcode Wrapper.
 *
 * @param string[] $function Callback function.
 * @param array    $atts     Attributes. Default to empty array.
 * @param array    $wrapper  Customer wrapper data.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function shortcode_wrapper(
    $function,
    $atts = array(),
    $wrapper = array(
        'class'  => 'woocommerce',
        'before' => null,
        'after'  => null,
    )
) {
    ob_start();

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    echo empty( $wrapper['before'] ) ? '<main class="' . esc_attr( $wrapper['class'] ) . '">' : $wrapper['before'];
    call_user_func( $function, $atts );
    echo empty( $wrapper['after'] ) ? '</main>' : $wrapper['after'];
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: i think you''ll need to do this via the template files in your child theme

Comment: In what pages were you trying to change this? Did you manage to do this?  
@blackchill24 It seems that it's generated dynamically via PHP class not a template

Comment: You could "hack" on that function directly, no need to override the plugin's files. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56664962/1152876