# Override Woocommerce Includes Class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to customise Woocommerce a little to create my own theme.

I have my own grid system which means I need to alter the class names some of the shortcodes are generating.

The main one in question is within plugins/woocommerce/includes. Now I know I shouldn't really edit this as every time there is an update it's like to revert back.

Is there a way I can easily override the class' the includes produces?

The main segment in question is within `class-wc-shortcodes.php`

```
return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
```

I've also tried moving the includes to within my theme directory at `/wp-content/MYTHEME/woocommerce/includes`. However this didn't override.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can achieve this by define same function into your current theme's function.php file with changes you required.

Please check this url (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482764/change-shortcode-wrapper-in-woocommerce)