# Unable to edit markup in woocommerce my account page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

the woo commerce template my-account.php has only this much code →

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation' ); ?>

<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
    <?php
        /**
         * My Account content.
         * @since 2.6.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_account_content' );
    ?>
</div>
```

I went ahead and searched a little bit more  about this "woocommerce_account_content"

I found [this one](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_account_content.html#2426-2450)

```
/**
     * My Account content output.
     */
    function woocommerce_account_content() {
        global $wp;

        if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars ) ) {
            foreach ( $wp->query_vars as $key => $value ) {
                // Ignore pagename param.
                if ( 'pagename' === $key ) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_account_' . $key . '_endpoint' ) ) {
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_account_' . $key . '_endpoint', $value );
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        // No endpoint found? Default to dashboard.
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/dashboard.php', array(
            'current_user' => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ),
        ) );
    }
```

I still didn't get the markup. Please guide me how should I add a custom mark up?
I think that these endpoints hold the clue, but I still couldn't figure out how?

Comment: WooCommerce My Account Page Consist of several sub pages, 
so what exactly do you want to change so we can point you to write direction? 
for example if you want to change orders page you need to look for orders.php inside the my account folder and also inside my account you can find all default subpages for my account

Comment: I have the same question as the O.P. Suppose If I want to change the menu section. I mean [this one](https://www.screencast.com/t/o0E0oW4mo), for example. How can I launch my custom markup/html/css

Comment: @somethingnow i will be in front of my computer within an hour and i will write some explanation with examples as answer if nobody answered

Comment: I am waiting along with the O.P. I believe this will also answer her query. If we have clue how to edit one thing others can be dealt with accordingly. My question is specifically related to how to add my own markup overriding woocommerce's markup.

Comment: @somethingnow check the answer below i hope it will be helpful for you too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an explanation about WooCommerce My account page template and how to override the html markup.

In my example am going to use twitter bootstrap.

WooCommerce My account basically is a page with several subpages which you can switch between the subpages through the navigation.

The main main markup consists of two div one for the navigation and one for the content it self

The hierarchy of my account subpages as follow:

```
My-account Main Page -> my-account.php : 
                  - dashboard.php 
                  - downloads.php 
                  - form-add-payment-method.php
                  - form-edit-account
                  - form-edit-address
                  - form-login.php
                  - form-lost-password.php
                  - form-reset-password.php
                  - list-password-confirmation.php
                  - my-address.php
                  - my-download.php
                  - navigation.php
                  - orders.php
                  - payment-methods.php
                  - view-order.php
```

**Example 1:**

let’s say we want to wrap the main content with bootstrap grid system.

In order to achieve that you need to go to `my-account.php` and add the required div and classes as follow:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
        <?php do_action('woocommerce_account_navigation');?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-9">

            <?php
/**
 * My Account content.
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
do_action('woocommerce_account_content');
?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2:**

Let’s say you want to modify the navigation so you can have bootstrap `nav-pills` style:

Go to `navigation.php`  and add the required classes as follow:

```
<ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills my_account_nav"  >
    <?php foreach (wc_get_account_menu_items() as $endpoint => $label):
     global $wp;
     $current = isset($wp->query_vars[$endpoint]);
      ?>
        <li class="nav-item <?php echo wc_get_account_menu_item_classes($endpoint); ?>">
        <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($current) ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_account_endpoint_url($endpoint)); ?>"> <?php echo esc_html($label); ?>
        </a>
        </li>
     <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
```

And If you need to change the other subpages template you need to go to the specific template you want  and write  your markup  modification in there.

I hope this is clear enough for you.

Comment: This is a great insight. I hope O.P. will also benefit from this.

Comment: what roles and functions are they doing → `woocommerce_before_account_navigation`  and `woocommerce_after_account_navigation`

Comment: Thank you for the help I have some more concern from where is this div coming → `<div class="woocommerce">` | https://www.screencast.com/t/Pb7xnlIy8

Comment: it's coming from `shortcode_wrapper` method inside `class-wc-shortcodes.php`

Comment: Can you also guide me how to change it. I mean which file should I try changing.

Comment: there is no hook or function to remove this div you need to use javascript for that or wrap the shortcode with your own html

Comment: I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482764/change-shortcode-wrapper-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Hi @kashalo. This code does not seem to work anymore. I have added `global $wp; $current = isset($wp->query_vars[$endpoint]);` and then in the class added `<?php echo ($current) ? 'active' : ''; ?>` but this is not picking up the current endpoint and echoing the active class?